# How to create custom Attention layer for 1D-CNN on Tabular Data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to create a custom layer for multiclass classification problem in a Tabular dataset using 1d-cnn. my original dataset has ~20000 features and ~5000000 rows with 8 classes. It suffers from severe imbalance, so I want to add attention layer to the 1D-CNNs such that the minority classes are paid attention to. To simplify the problem I will show the model I built on Iris Dataset. I would like to check if what I am doing is correct, the aim is to add attention to 1D-cnn layers in a VGG variant model. I would appreciate any help and input.

```
# Load libraries
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

## Plotting Library
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
## File I/O
import os

## ML & DeepL libraries: 
import tensorflow.keras 
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import np_utils  # This library has been separated from keras and tensorflow. 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Conv1D, Dropout, BatchNormalization, MaxPooling1D, LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, StratifiedShuffleSplit
## ML & DL Model Evaluaiton Libraries_Classes: 
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight

# preprocessing libraries: 
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale

# Compute sample weights using sklearn: 
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_sample_weight
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential




# load Iris
data = load_iris()
# Get the X features and corresponding labels: 
X_ = data['data']
y_ = data['target']

X_ = X_[0:]
y_ = y_[0:]
Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X_, y_, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Creat attention layer:

```
# Add attention layer to the deep learning network
class attention(Layer):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(attention,self).__init__(**kwargs)
 
    def build(self,input_shape):
        self.W=self.add_weight(name='attention_weight', 
                               shape=(input_shape[-1],1), 
                               initializer='random_normal',
                               trainable=True)
        self.b=self.add_weight(name='attention_bias', 
                               shape=(input_shape[1],1), 
                               initializer='zeros',
                               trainable=True)        
        super(attention, self).build(input_shape)
 
    def call(self,x):
        # Alignment scores. Pass them through tanh function
        e = K.tanh(K.dot(x,self.W)+self.b)
        # Remove dimension of size 1
        e = K.squeeze(e, axis=-1)   
        # Compute the weights
        alpha = K.softmax(e)
        # Reshape to tensorFlow format
        alpha = K.expand_dims(alpha, axis=-1)
        # Compute the context vector
        context = x * alpha
        context = K.sum(context, axis=1)
        return context
```

Create 1D-CNN with attention:

```
hidden_units = 2
epochs = 40
activation = ['tanh', 'tanh']
def create_cnn_with_attention(hidden_units, 
                              dense_units, 
                              input_shape,
                              activation):
    
    x=Input(shape=input_shape)
    
    cnn_layer = Conv1D(filters=64,
            kernel_size       =21,
            strides           =1,
            padding           ='same',
            activation        ='relu',
            input_shape       = input_shape,
            kernel_initializer= tensorflow.keras.initializers.he_normal())(x)
    
    
    attention_layer = attention()(cnn_layer)
    outputs=Dense(dense_units, 
                  trainable=True, 
                  activation=activation)(attention_layer)
    
    model=Model(x,outputs)
    
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                  optimizer='adam',
                 metrics = ['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])    
    return model    
 
model_attention = create_cnn_with_attention(hidden_units=hidden_units,
                                                dense_units=3, 
                                                input_shape = (input_shape),
                                                activation='tanh')

model_attention.summary()
```

Model: "model_12"

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

input_14 (InputLayer)        [(None, 4, 1)]            0

---

conv1d_18 (Conv1D)           (None, 4, 64)             1408

---

attention_12 (attention)     (None, 64)                68

---

## dense_14 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 195

Total params: 1,671
Trainable params: 1,671
Non-trainable params: 0

---

```
model_attention.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, epochs = 40)
```

Epoch 1/40
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 11.0361 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.3100
Epoch 2/40
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 10.8962 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.3100
Epoch 3/40
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 10.6803 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.1000
Epoch 4/40
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 2.7534 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/40
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/40
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/40
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/40
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00  ....

```
train_mse_attn = model_attention.evaluate(Xtrain, ytrain)
```

4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1.0986 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00